# unexpected scanf behavior

Tags: c

Why is the output of the given code like this ??

```
int main(){

int a,b,c;

scanf("%3d %3d %3 d",&a,&b,&c);

printf("%d %d %d",a,b,c);
}
```

The input which i gave was 1234 5678.

Suddenly it is showing output as 123 4 567.

Can anyone please explain why this output came ?

Comment: The output is either a compiler error, or you didn't mean to have a space in `scanf` (which @m.s. removed for you, and you edited it back out... why?)

Comment: With this you may get error in output . That third variable doesn't match with nay specifier.

Comment: Not testing the return value of scanf is a sure recipe for surprises.

Comment: @R_Kapp The edit back is a result of SO:s semi-retarded edit system, rather than something done intentionally by the OP. Users ms and jkrish both edited the post at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

First: If you compiled the code exactly as it is shown note that there is a space between the last `%3` and the `d`, so `scanf` will not read the last value because there is no third `%3d` flag.

Second: You used `scanf` with a `3` between `%` and `d` it means you limit the width of the integers read to 3 digits so the number you typed, `5678` should be read just 567.

My suggestion: write the `scanf` line as

```
scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
```

this way you can give it integers with more or less digits.

Comment: Good answer.  Detail: 3 limits the non-space width of `char`, not only digits.  Consider `"-12345"` would only scan in `"-12"`.

Answer (score 2):

```
scanf("%3d %3d %3 d",&a,&b,&c);
```

Input: 1234 5678

Output: 123 456 -1217434035

Because your expression `%3 d` is messed up.

If you change the entire thing to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int a,b,c;

scanf("%3d %3d %3d",&a,&b,&c);

printf("%d %d %d",a,b,c);
}
```

You get (presumably expected) output:

> 123 4 567

What happens:

`123` is read into `a` (you specified 3 characters)

`4` is read into `b` (scanf stops on space by default)

`567` is read into `c` (you specified 3 characters)

Comment: I don't think that will be output .

Comment: @ameyCU https://ideone.com/7Xj3r7

Comment: I don't get that on my system . It gives `123 4 567` .

Comment: @ameyCU NVM; I figured out whats wrong, will edit answer asap.

Comment: @ameyCU Edited answer.

Comment: Hmm, the input was different that's why output was .